# Sagepay Server Integration 5003 error code on first POST

Tags: opayo

I'm attempting to initiate a test transaction with sagepay by POSTing to https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp

I've followed the documentation with regards to the format such a request should take, I've whitelisted my IP in the portal on the test environment and I'm using `VPSProtocol=3.00` (Which are the two problems that I've seen reported to cause this) but I'm still getting a 5003 error.

I've spoken to support on the phone and POSTed to their showpost endpoint (https://test.sagepay.com/showpost/showpost.asp). It doesn't seem to be able to understand any of the details of my POST despite it being in a `Name=Value` format separated by `&`, URL encoding the values like the documentation dictates and providing all the required fields.

I've tried URL encoding the `=`s as well as the `&`s just in case I had misunderstood the documentation in that regards but it didn't make any difference.

I believe that I must be sending the body incorrectly somehow. I'd appreciate any suggestions anyone can give. The body I'm sending is below:

```
VPSProtocol=3.00&TxType=PAYMENT&Vendor=anyjunko&VendorTxCode=123&Amount=143.33&Currency=GBP&Description=TODO&NotificationURL=https%3A%2F%2Fstaging-nelly.anyjunk.co.uk%2Fvs%2Fsagepay-transactions%2F1%2Fsagepay-updates&BillingSurname=NameB&BillingFirstnames=NameA&BillingAddress1=1&BillingAddress2=Putney&BillingCity=London&BillingPostCode=SW11%209YZ&BillingCountry=GB&DeliverySurname=NameB&DeliveryFirstnames=NameA&DeliveryAddress1=1&DeliveryAddress2=Putney&DeliveryCity=London&DeliveryPostCode=SW11%209YZ&DeliveryCountry=GB
```

Update: I've now tried this with cURL and it worked correctly, but it doesn't work when I send it from Postman or from my code using akka http client.

The cURL command I used was:

```
curl -X POST "https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspserver-register.vsp" -d "VPSProtocol=3.00&TxType=PAYMENT&Vendor=anyjunko&VendorTxCode=123&Amount=143.33&Currency=GBP&Description=TODO&NotificationURL=https%3A%2F%2Fstaging-nelly.anyjunk.co.uk%2Fvs%2Fsagepay-transactions%2F1%2Fsagepay-updates&BillingSurname=NameB&BillingFirstnames=NameA&BillingAddress1=1&BillingAddress2=Putney&BillingCity=London&BillingPostCode=SW11%209YZ&BillingCountry=GB&DeliverySurname=NameB&DeliveryFirstnames=NameA&DeliveryAddress1=1&DeliveryAddress2=Putney&DeliveryCity=London&DeliveryPostCode=SW11%209YZ&DeliveryCountry=GB"
```

Comment: How are you posting? What headers are you sending? You need to give more details please.

Comment: For testing purposes I'm using Postman to send the POST with no headers.

Comment: I tried it with cURL now and it works. It still doesn't work with Postman or from my code (using akka http client). I'm not sure what the difference is though. Presumably there's a header that cURL's sending that I'm not from the others or vice-versa.

Comment: I have the same problem using Fiddler or C# HttpWebRequest, I think there must be an undocumented HTTP header requirement or some undocument required settings in testportal.sagepay.com

Answer (score 1):

There are some requirements missing from the Sage Pay documentation which must be provided otherwise you will get a HTTP 500 Internal Error 5003

Documentation for Server Integration named
"SERVER_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_270815.pdf" is available here:
https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document/server-inframe-integration-documents

First make sure that you have followed the documentation to the letter, especially be careful to include all the mandatory fields and URLencode the values of the name=value pairs.

The following requirements are not mentioned in the documentation:

**1 IP Addresses**

The IP address from which you send your POST to ~/vspserver-register.vsp must be added to the whitelist on your account settings.

1. login to My Sage Pay here https://testportal.sagepay.com/mysagepay/login.msp using your administrator account (usually your vendor name)
2. Go to "IP Válidas" (sorry admin suite is in Spanish for some reason)
3. Click [Añadir] ("Add") button in bottom right
4. In the dialog that pops up enter your

   - "Dirección IP" ("IP address") - type "Whats my IP" into a Google search if you don't know it
   - your "Máscara de subred" ("Subnet mask") - 255.255.255.000
   - "Descripción" - just any name you want, has to be unique
5. Click [Añadir] ("Add") button

**2 Firewall**

Make sure your firewall is not blocking ports 80 and 443 for HTTP or SSL in either direction

**3 HTTPS Protocol**

Make sure that you are POSTing to the server using TLS version 1.0 or higher. Also make sure you can use one of the TLS protocols, at time of writing Sage Pay only supports these protocols

- TLS1-AES-256-CBC-SHA
- TLS1-AES-128-CBC-SHA
- TLS1-DHE-DSS-RC4-SHA
- TLS1-DHE-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA
- TLS1-DHE-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA
- TLS1-DHE-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA
- TLS1-DHE-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA

**4 HTTP Headers**

There is only one HTTP header required, although it still works if you pass in extra headers such as "Host" or "Content-Length" it will fail if you do not provide exactly

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```